# MassTransit- The host path must be empty or contain a single virtual host name

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm totally new to RabbitMQ and MassTransit. I just have a code that worked in dev environment but in production I get the error mentioned in the title.
Currently the configuration is as follows:

```
<source name="mdb" switchValue="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="MM" type="Comp.MyTraceListener, Comp.Diagnostics"
           initializeData="rabbitmq://server.xxx.int/ProdRabbitCluster/MDB"
           username="prod" password="xxxxx" />
    </listeners>
  </source>'
```

Just to check I decompiled MassTransit DLL and found that it's because the `"/ProdRabbitCluster/MDB"` has more than one `"/"` separated segment.

So is this URL format simply invalid and should be changed? That value was given by customer's admins and I have no idea about their whole infrastructure and servers.

Comment: Oh, and rather than decompile, you could just look at the source code: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of a URL for MassTransit using RabbitMQ is:

```
rabbitmq://hostname[:port]/virtual_host
```

There shouldn't be another '/' in the virtual host name. It may be legal for RabbitMQ, but it isn't legal for MassTransit. They'll need to rename the virtual host to not include a '/' in the name.

*I don't understand why operations does things like this sometimes.*